# jqGrid custom editfunc doesn't work when custom search parameters are specified

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Version jqGrid used here:
@license Guriddo jqGrid JS - v5.2.0 - 2016-11-27  Copyright(c) 2008, Tony Tomov, tony@trirand.com

The first block of code below is an entire self contained implementation of jqGrid. It is in fact mostly taken from one of the examples on the jqGrid site.  In it I added a snippet, the part between the comment lines with the clip markings.

That added snipped adds a custom editfunc. It works nicely (in the example it is of course more or less a stub, only doing an alert).  Also, searching works, with all of its default parameters.  For both, select a row and click on the respective icon of Edit or Search.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- The jQuery library is a prerequisite for all jqSuite products -->
    <script type="text/ecmascript" src="./lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- This is the Javascript file of jqGrid -->
    <script type="text/ecmascript" src="./lib/jqGrid-js-free/js/jquery.jqGrid.js"></script>
    <!-- This is the localization file of the grid controlling messages, labels, etc.-->
    <!-- We support more than 40 localizations -->
    <script type="text/ecmascript" src="./lib/jqGrid-js-free/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <!-- A link to a jQuery UI ThemeRoller theme, more than 22 built-in and many more custom -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="./lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css" />
    <!-- The link to the CSS that the grid needs -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="./lib/jqGrid-js-free/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jqGrid without PHP - Loading Data - JSON Live</title>
</head>
<body>

    <table id="jqGrid"></table>
    <div id="jqGridPager"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
                colModel: [
                    {
                        label: 'Title',
                        name: 'Title',
                        width: 150,
                        formatter: formatTitle
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Link',
                        name: 'Link',
                        width: 80,
                        formatter: formatLink
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'View Count',
                        name: 'ViewCount',
                        width: 35,
                        sorttype:'integer',
                        formatter: 'number',
                        align: 'right'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Answer Count',
                        name: 'AnswerCount',
                        width: 25
                    }
                ],

                viewrecords: true, // show the current page, data rang and total records on the toolbar
                width: 780,
                height: 200,
                rowNum: 15,
                datatype: 'local',
                pager: "#jqGridPager",
                caption: "Load live data from stackoverflow"
            });

            fetchGridData();

            function fetchGridData() {

                var gridArrayData = [];
                // show loading message
                $("#jqGrid")[0].grid.beginReq();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=jqgrid&site=stackoverflow",
                    success: function (result) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < result.items.length; i++) {
                            var item = result.items[i];
                            gridArrayData.push({
                                Title: item.title,
                                Link: item.link,
                                CreationDate: item.creation_date,
                                ViewCount: item.view_count,
                                AnswerCount: item.answer_count
                            });
                        }
                        // set the new data
                        $("#jqGrid").jqGrid('setGridParam', { data: gridArrayData});
                        // hide the show message
                        $("#jqGrid")[0].grid.endReq();
                        // refresh the grid
                        $("#jqGrid").trigger('reloadGrid');
                    }
                });
            }

            function formatTitle(cellValue, options, rowObject) {
                return cellValue.substring(0, 50) + "...";
            };

            function formatLink(cellValue, options, rowObject) {
                return "<a href='" + cellValue + "'>" + cellValue.substring(0, 25) + "..." + "</a>";
            };

            /*---- 8< ------*/
            // editfunc here works (an alert is popped up), although the format of the function parameters is not according to spec:
            // searchfunc also works (it is the default)

            $('#jqGrid').jqGrid( 'navGrid', '#jqGridPager',{
                add:false, del:false, view:false,
                editfunc: function(){alert('EDIT');}
            });
            /*---- >8 ------*/

        });

    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Now take the same file, remove the small snippet between the snip lines, and replace it with the following snippet, that looks more like something I need to implement:

```
    /*---- 8< ------*/
    // editfunc does NOT work as desired here (no alert)
    // search function works, WITH the parameters as specified here
    // from the file jquery.jqGrid.js (): navGrid : function parameters: (elem, p, pEdit, pAdd, pDel, pSearch, pView)
    // (=jqGrid-free @license Guriddo jqGrid JS - v5.2.0 - 2016-11-27  Copyright(c) 2008, Tony Tomov, tony@trirand.com)

    $('#jqGrid').jqGrid( 'navGrid', '#jqGridPager',
        { add:false, del:false, view:false },           // p
        { editfunc: function(r){alert('EDIT');} },      // pEdit    (does NOT work)
        { },                                            // pAdd
        { },                                            // pDel
        { multipleSearch: true, closeAfterSearch:true, closeOnEscape:true, searchOnEnter:true, showQuery:true },    // pSearch (works with these options)
        { }                                             // pView
    );
    /*---- >8 ------*/
```

Here, alas the editfunc does not work at all, I get the default edit function. Search now works though, as desired with the custom specified parameters.

In short: I cannot seem to get both a customized editfunc and search with custom parameters working!

I cannot see anything wrong with the second snippet. It is btw. also per some examples on the jqGrid wiki.

Any hints to get both working together would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is very easy: you placed `editfunc` in the wrong place in your last snippet. The `editfunc` should be specified as the property of the second parameter of `navGrid` (together with `add:false, del:false, view:false`). You used the `editfunc` correctly in the first part of your code, but you placed it in the second part of the code on the wrong place. You can fix your code by usage

```
$('#jqGrid').jqGrid( 'navGrid', '#jqGridPager',
    { add:false, del:false, view:false, editfunc: function(r){alert('EDIT');} },  // p
    { },      // pEdit
    { },                                            // pAdd
    { },                                            // pDel
    { multipleSearch: true, closeAfterSearch:true, closeOnEscape:true,
        searchOnEnter:true, showQuery:true },       // pSearch (works with these options)
    { }                                             // pView
);
```

By the way, you placed the code of *commercial* product Guriddo jqGrid JS in the directory `jqGrid-js-free`, which sounds strange. Guriddo jqGrid JS can't be used for free. You can see the current prices [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334). I started development of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork of jqGrid, which can be used completely free of charge,  exactly because of that. Free jqGrid implemented many new features, which can be helpful for you. The demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/odvxefra/3/ is a small modification of your code, which displays

[image]

I used additionally

```
url: "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions",
// add sending of custom parameters to the URL
postData: {
    order: "desc",
    sort: "activity",
    tagged: "jqgrid",
    site: "stackoverflow"
},
datatype: "json",
// below prmNames remove sending all standard jqGrid paranmeters
prmNames: {
    page: null,
    rows: null,
    sort: null,
    order: null,
    search: null,
    nd: null,
    id: "question_id"
},
jsonReader: {
    root: "items",
    repeatitems: false,
    id: "question_id"
},
loadonce: true,
forceClientSorting: true,
sortname: "creation_date",
sortorder: "desc"
```

The data will be loaded from the same URL "http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=jqgrid&site=stackoverflow", sorted *locally* by `creation_date` property in the desc order and displayed in the grid. One can use other properties in the custom formatter by adding the properties in `additionalProperties`. For example you can add `additionalProperties: ["owner", "is_answered", "score", "last_activity_date"]` to save the properties locally and to have access to the properties inside of, for example, custom formatter.

Comment: Awesome. Looks like this solves my problem. Thank you very much!  As to the jqgrid code, I had been downloading quite a few versions lately to test php code, js code and whatnot and see what I might use in the current project. In the end I did find your free-jqgrid a few weeks ago.  I could have sworn I created all of the required symlinks to use your implementation, but apparently with all the versioning and testing I forgot to change some url's in my code...  So thanks for the hint in that regard as well!

Comment: @Roadowl: You are welcome! I modified the demo a little. See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/odvxefra/3/

Comment: Nice... maybe a bit too blingy for me though... ;-)   Thanks again!